# how to make function taking reverse of an HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have a sample code like this

```
implicit def func[T <: HList, F, R](
  implicit fp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, Reverse[T]#Out => R], 
  rev: Reverse[T]): (F, T) => R = 
  (f: F, t: T) => f.toProduct(t.reverse)
```

So what I want is to ask compiler to implicitly resolve a function `F` take the reverse of an `HList` as its input and output `R`. For example,

```
type R = java.util.Date
type F2 = Function2[String, Int, R]
type TT = Int :: String :: HNil

implicitly[(F2, TT) => R]
```

though the `implicit func` compiles, the above example code fails to resolve the implicit I was thinking it should be able to find. What is wrong with it ?

Comment: seems like the issue lies on the `implicit FnToProduct.Aux` cannot be resolved. `implicitly[FnToProduct.Aux[F2, String :: Int :: HNil => R]]` compiles, while `implicitly[FnToProduct.Aux[F2, Reverse[TT]#Out => R]]` doesn't. How to make it work ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type projections are rarely useful in Shapeless, since the compiler statically doesn't know much about e.g. `Reverse[T]#Out`. It'd be nice if you could write `rev.Out` in its place, but you can't (that's [a long story](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2015/07/11/roll-your-own-scala/)…). Instead you'll need to add a type parameter to represent the reversed `HList`:

```
import shapeless._, ops.function.FnToProduct, ops.hlist.Reverse

implicit def func[T <: HList, TR <: HList, F, R](implicit
  fp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, TR => R],
  rev: Reverse.Aux[T, TR]
): (F, T) => R = (f: F, t: T) => fp(f)(rev(t))
```

This will work as expected, although I'd suggest not putting a function like this into implicit scope.

Comment: That works. I am just making up an example to describe the problem I was running into :) Won't place it into implicit scope anyway. Thanks a lot!